# How to get the URL source code part of a jwplayer

Tags: php, html, regex, jwplayer

Good day friends...

How to get the URL source code part of a jwplayer, I mean the mp4 part, and I found what I'm looking for here [the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185549/grab-scrap-the-source-file-of-a-web-pagejwplayer-source)

I try to used it but I can't do it right, sorry for my bad english, can someone take a look at my php code below....I want to grab the link http://localhost/srt/43534234/viral022018SD.MP4 and http://localhost/srt/43534234/viral022018HD.MP4 or all mp4 URL inside it in the viral022018.html

Thank you hope someone help me...thank you

This is my php code

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://localhost/video/viral022018.html');
//$dom->loadHtml('', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$sources = [];
foreach ($xpath->query("//script[@type=\"text/javascript\"]") as $script) {
    if (stristr($script->nodeValue, 'playerInstance') !== false) {
        preg_match_all('#file: \"(.+)\"#', $script->nodeValue, $match);
        $sources = $match[1];
    }
}

print_r($sources);
?>
```

This is the viral022018.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanuman' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scada" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jwplayer-7.12.8/skins/prime.min2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer-7.12.8/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="I9HOJrL1NmqruQ60as34wt34/23422dsdrwer==";</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="picasa" class="picasa"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("picasa");
        playerInstance.setup({
        id:'picasa',
        controls: true,
        displaytitle: true,

        flashplayer: "//ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.12.5/jwplayer.flash.swf",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        fullscreen: "true",
        provider: 'http',
        autostart: false,
        image:'http://localhost/viral/viralvideo.jpg',
            sources: [{file:"http://localhost/srt/43534234/viral022018SD.MP4",label:"SD",type: "video/mp4"},{file:"http://localhost/srt/43534234/viral022018HD.MP4",label:"HD",type: "video/mp4",default: true}],
            sharing:{
                link: "",
                code: "",
                heading: "Share",
                sites: ["facebook","twitter","tumblr","googleplus","reddit","linkedin","interest","email"],
            },
sharing:{
                link: "",
                code: "",
                heading: "Share",
                sites: ["facebook","twitter","tumblr","googleplus","reddit","linkedin","interest","email"],
            },
tracks: [{
            file: 'http://localhost/srt/viralvideo022018.srt',
            label: 'English',
            kind: 'captions',
            "default":true
}],

     captions: {
        color: '#FFEB3B',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontFamily: 'Scada, Hanuman, sans-serif, Verdana, cursive',
        fontOpacity: 100,
        backgroundOpacity: 0,
backgroundColor: '#000000',
        edgeStyle: 'raised',
        windowColor: '#000000',
        windowOpacity: 0
    },
skin: {
        name: 'prime',
    },




          });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the correction..its already updated...

Comment: someone help me about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this regex:

```
{\s*file\s*:\s*["']\s*(http[^"']+\.mp4)
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/rmgKId/2

The matched URL is in group 1.

(EDIT: added `\.mp4` to make it specific to those files)

EDIT: To implement in PHP generically you'd do something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/{\s*file\s*:\s*["\']\s*(http[^"\']+\.mp4)/i', $subject,
    $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[1];
```

`$result` will be an array of all the text matched by numbering group 1 in the regex. But I leave it to you to slot into your code above (change variable names to match what you want).

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a generic way of implementing that regex in PHP, which you can adapt according to the specifics of your code. Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah, the link and code you provided is working but, when it comes my local server, it doesn't work,..I still want to used file_gets_content  to this URL https://localhost/video/viral022018.html

I implement your code to my php code but it doesn't work..is it ok if you can make it with my sample php code above and implement your regex code....

Comment: again I tried with file_gets_contents with my links https://localhost/video/viral022018.html but nothings shows

$re = '/{\s*file\s*:\s*["\']\s*(http[^"\']+\.mp4)/mi';
$str = file_get_contents('http://localhost/video/viral022018.html');

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the methods you're using in PHP, but it looks to me like you're using two conflicting approaches. On the one hand you're using XPath to parse the DOM, and on the other you're using a regex to grab raw data from the HTML. I think you need to do one or the other. Why not try running my code directly on your $html variable. If the $html variable contains he HTML inside viral022018.html , as you pasted it above, then the regex should just grab the two matches and store them in $result (as an array). You may be over-complicating the code with unnecessary XPath...